# The template specified in the scratch org definition is unapproved. Contact Salesforce Support to request template approval

Tags: scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file

While creating the scratch org using SFDX CLI with Command as below:

```
sfdx force:org:create -s -f <SCRATCH ORG DEFINITON FILE> -a <ALIAS NAME> -d <DURATION>
sfdx force:org:create -s -f <SCRATCH ORG DEFINITON FILE> -a <ALIAS NAME> -d <DURATION>
```

I am getting this error. "The template specified in the scratch org definition is unapproved. Contact Salesforce Support to request template approval."

Comment: Do you have a `"template"` key in your scratch org definition file?

Comment: yes I do have, I ask developer to check the key..

Answer (score 1):

sfdx force:org:create -s -f -a -d

The command you are trying to give is incomplete

-f is a key which will expect the value as a file path to the definition file
-d is a key it will expect a value for how many days you need to keep the scratch org
-a will be the alias for the org you will be creating

Comment: I am using the file path to the definition file under -d. here is the command.. Apologies for the half command. Strange it's not reflecting in my existing question..
sfdx force:org:create -s -f <SCRATCH ORG DEFINITON FILE> -a <ALIAS NAME> -d <DURATION>

Comment: I think then the issue is with the Org definition file that you are using to create the org. can you post it over here by any chance ?